# nginx proxy_pass to url based on request

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to configure nginx (or apache) to use a different backend server based on the request domain?

For example:

```
For a request for srv1.pod1.mydomain.com should go to srv1.pod1.external  
For a request for srv1.pod2.mydomain.com should go to srv1.pod2.external  
...  
For a request for srv1.podN.mydomain.com should go to srv1.podN.external
```

I was looking at the rewrite rule but it doesn't seem to rewrite the domain, just the path.

```
server {
        listen 80 ([^.]+).(\w+).mydomain.com;

        server_name _;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                proxy_pass $1.$2.external;
        }
}
```

Comment: You should use named captures and you need to specify a scheme for the `proxy_pass` statement. It would be more efficient and secure to use several `server` blocks rather than a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config seems a little broken. Server names does not apply to `listen` directive, also you have a mistakes in your regular expressions. Try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<sub1>[^\.]+)\.(?<sub2>\w+)\.mydomain\.com;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $sub1.$sub2.external;
        proxy_pass http://$sub1.$sub2.external;
    }
}
```

When you specify your backend server with domain name, you need to specify the additional parameter [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) in your server config. You can use your local name server if you have one, or use something external like Google public DNS (8.8.8.8) or DNS provided for you by your ISP.